# Use python requests post with header for API authentication

Tags: python, header, python-requests

This curl command works:

```
curl -X GET 172.168.0.101/api/v1/events/ -H 'Authorization: Token 353e5axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

I want to do the same in python and requests seems like a good lib.

However:

```
import requests

header = {'Authorization': 'Token 353e5axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
r = requests.post('http://172.168.0.101/api/v1/events/', headers=header)
print r
```

does not work. It results in a 400 response.

Comment: I've never used Python requests before, but it seems that with curl you are doing a GET, but with Python requests you are doing a POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `requests.get()` instead:

```
r = requests.get('http://172.168.0.101/api/v1/events/', headers=header)
```

The `post` method you used sends a POST request, while your `curl` command line clearly uses GET instead. The 400 error returned indicates POST is the wrong method.